# I'm trying to use a variable outside of its function in python

Tags: python, function, variables

I'm not sure how I could get my ans_label to access my ans_string as it is defined within the function ssInterpret().

```py
def ssInterpret():
    #region=(x, y, width, height)
    time.sleep(5)
    myScreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(400, 320, 800, 500))
    myScreenshot.save(imgPath)

    #reads the image

    img = cv2.imread(imgPath)
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

    q = text

    #completes the answer search

    results = brainlypy.search(q)
    question = results.questions[0]
    print('URL: '+'https://brainly.com/task/'+str(question.databaseid))
    print('QUESTION:',question)
    print('ANSWER 1:', question.answers[0])
    if question.answers_count == 2:
        print('ANSWER 2:', question.answers[1])

    ans_string = str(question.answers[0])

answer_label = Label(root, text=ans_string)
```

Comment: You can use ```global``` variable to do this.

Comment: Your current code never even calls `ssInterpret`, so that code is never going to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your function needs to return the answer:

```py
def ssInterpret():
    ...  # most of function elided.
    return ans_string

#then call the function 
ans = ssInterpret()
answer_label = Label(root, text=ans)
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `ans_string` as `ans_string = ""` at the top of your code. Then add a line `global ans_string` prior to `ans_string = str(question.answers[0])` inside the function `ssInterpret()`. Call `ssInterpret()` before `answer_label = Label(root, text=ans_string)`. Your code should now work as expected.

Complete code with modification:

```
ans_string = ""

def ssInterpret():
    #region=(x, y, width, height)
    time.sleep(5)
    myScreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(400, 320, 800, 500))
    myScreenshot.save(imgPath)

    #reads the image

    img = cv2.imread(imgPath)
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

    q = text

    #completes the answer search

    results = brainlypy.search(q)
    question = results.questions[0]
    print('URL: '+'https://brainly.com/task/'+str(question.databaseid))
    print('QUESTION:',question)
    print('ANSWER 1:', question.answers[0])
    if question.answers_count == 2:
        print('ANSWER 2:', question.answers[1])

    global ans_string
    ans_string = str(question.answers[0])

ssInterpret()
answer_label = Label(root, text=ans_string)
```

Comment: Nooooo! Avoiding global variables is easy in this case: just return the string.

Comment: Yeah of course, that's one way of doing it :)